# Basis of an infinite dimensional Banach space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Can somebody please check the correctness of this proof, since I am new to this? 
Thank you in advance.

Given $X$ a normed space and $Y$ a proper subset of $X$ that is a linear subspace, prove that $int Y$ is empty.

Proof:
Assume $Y$ is nowhere dense. 
$X/int(CL (Y)) = CL(X/CL (Y)) = X$ by definition of nowhere dense set. So $Y$ nowhere dense implies $int (CL (Y)) = \emptyset$.

Consequence:
The space $X$ belongs to the 1st category of Baire, from this follows a non-positive characteristic of the space, such that: any metric in this space is not complete wrt to topology and the closure of any [non-empty] pen set is not compact.

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning, which apart of being excessively complicated smells of error. Note that $X$ is not assumed to be a Banach space, hence you have no Baire category theorem. I would rather argue by contradiction and assume that $Y$ contains an open ball. Why does this contradict the fact that $Y$ is proper?

Comment: Moreover, what do bases have to do with this?

Comment: thank you   Giuseppe Negro , then if I assume that Y contains an open ball, then interior of Y is not empty.Then applying Baire category theorem Y should be equal to X and X is the union of countable closed sets. And the arbitrary union of closed sets is closed. Am I on the right way?

Comment: No. Forget about Baire category theorem I said.

Answer (score 1):

In the first paragraph of your attempt you "deduce", from $Y$ nowhere dense, that $\text{int}(CL(Y))=\emptyset$. That's usually just the definition of nowhere dense, so as far as I can see you get nothing from the first paragraph.

To do an actual proof, I suggest you try first with $X=\mathbb R^2$ and $Y=\mathbb R$.

Comment: thank you, Martin Argerami

Comment: You're welcome!